# Startup Error on Win10

Tags: neo4j

Getting an error trying to start Neo4j on Windows 10:
[image]

Any thoughts from anywhere? Nothing in Operations Guide or Developers Guide talks about this DB. This is CE edition, running locally.

System log had this about the failure:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-08T15:40:28.976232300Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>14535</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>omitted</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>129168941443</Data> 
  <Data>5</Data> 
  <Data>RADAR_PRE_LEAK_64</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>neo4j-ce.exe</Data> 
  <Data>0.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data>10.0.14393.2.0.0</Data> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\Users\lschill\AppData\Local\Temp\RDRB4ED.tmp\empty.txt \\?    \C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB50E.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>8d3dd2f1-0415-11e7-96b5-d481d7785562</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>79b1c284dc68f120300f3bcf10cd53ef</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

AppData and ProgramData files referenced did not exist when I looked.

Comment: can you add attached cause exception ?

Comment: Can't find it, not in any logs I could locate.

Comment: Do you have JAVA 8 installed ?

Comment: I do now, Java 8 Update 121. Same error occurs. Should I reinstall Neo4j?

Comment: neo4j has some issues with windows installer version. Can you try the zip version and follow https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137607/discussion-between-louis-schilling-and-tomaz-bratanic).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this error appears when you do not have installed JAVA 8 server JRE on your computer